# Css Divs overflow

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have 2 divs, first div must adapt height about content and second div must be height the remnant.
The second div must scroll to show all items
This is the template [image]

here my example [JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/maurosala/0q6z58ou/)
I don't want javascript, only CSS

```
<div class="tbl">
  <div class="header">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    <div class="in-body">
        <p>3</p>
        <p>4</p>
        <p>5</p>
        <p>6</p>
        <p>7</p>
        <p>8</p>
        <p>9</p>
        <p>10</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to this way http://rohitazadmalik.blogspot.in/2014/03/section-have-fixed-position-when-it.html

Comment: This can be achieved via CSS if you provide one answer: what happens to the second div when the first one is 100% of viewport height? How tall will it be?

Comment: I don't know the height of first div

Comment: the first div will be always less height than page size, it will be about 200 or 250 px, no more

Comment: Your HTML is wrong. Div is unclosed.

Comment: Ok, So what is the min height of second div? And what happens when it reaches it? Do you want a scroll on the page or on the first div?

Comment: here the fiddle edited, first div has inline items and I don't know the width of the page https://jsfiddle.net/maurosala/0q6z58ou/6/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here it is. I made the second div be at least 35% of window height. If you want the min height of second div to be higher or smaller, adjust the 65vh on the wrapper. (100vh is the viewport and what's not wrapper height is second div height).

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 35%;
  max-height: 65vh;
  position: relative;
}
.first,
.second {
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.first {
  background-color: green;
}
.second {
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  height: calc(100vh - 100%);
  top: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="first">
    kitsch flannel direct trade listicle ramps truffaut.
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    Brunch fingerstache bespoke squid neutra. Cred hella meh, slow-carb kale chips fashion axe vinyl keytar banjo butcher ethical affogato taxidermy. Bicycle rights venmo lomo truffaut. Art party kickstarter vice, truffaut yr 90's farm-to-table. Banh mi try-hard
    distillery, next level mumblecore jean shorts sustainable drinking vinegar squid banjo 3 wolf moon. Slow-carb waistcoat fashion axe, try-hard kinfolk flexitarian hella pitchfork semiotics truffaut blue bottle stumptown. Asymmetrical skateboard distillery
    chambray.
  </div>
</div>
```